# Receiving 'Cannot anchor to a null item' when using States

Tags: qml

I have a rectangle with a fixed size that should always stay attached to the bottom of the vertical center of my window. If the window height gets small enough for the rectangle to touch the border I want to change the anchors of the rectangle for it to stick to the bottom of the window instead.

I achieved this using States:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 200
    height: 480
    minimumHeight: maxSize
    visible: true

    property int maxSize: 150
    property bool centerTop: maxSize < (height / 2)

    Rectangle {
        id: rect

        states: [
            State {
                name: "Centered"
                when: centerTop
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.bottom: undefined
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "Bottom"
                when: !centerTop
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    anchors.top: undefined
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                }
            }
        ]
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        height: maxSize
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: Result (gif)]

This works perfectly fine, but whenever I decreased the window size to reach the state *Bottom* and increase it again to reach the state *Centered* I get the error message
`qrc:/main.qml:14:5: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.`

Is there a solution or a better approach to my problem?

Comment: It's weird that it thinks the item is null, but I think the problem is you need to use an [AnchorChanges](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-anchorchanges.html#details) object instead of PropertyChanges.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss this one? Works like a charm! I would happy to accept your answer if you turn it into one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to make sure you use an [AnchorChanges](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-anchorchanges.html#details) instead of PropertyChanges when dealing with anchors. The docs don't give much of an explanation other than to say:

> PropertyChanges can be used to change anchor margins, but not other anchor values; use AnchorChanges for this instead.

```
        states: [
            State {
                name: "Centered"
                when: centerTop
                AnchorChanges {
                    target: rect
                    anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.bottom: undefined
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "Bottom"
                when: !centerTop
                AnchorChanges {
                    target: rect
                    anchors.top: undefined
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                }
            }
        ]
```